# MySql client prompt is occasionally broken

Tags: mysql, prompt, display

I've got a weird bug with the MySQL prompt which has always annoyed me. Sometimes when I type for example:

```
mysql > select * from users where
```

I will press backspace and the prompt will suddenly look broken like this:

```
mysql > mysql > om users wher
```

It will basically add a `mysql >` before and overwrite part of the query. Internally the query is still valid (if I finish it and press enter it will work) but it's the display that's broken.

I'm wondering what could be causing this? Is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: Do you have an `~/.inputrc` file with something in it that may be influencing the way that the Readline library handles the command line? (I believe that the `mysql` client uses Readline)

Comment: Are you using a colorized bash prompt? This can cause readline to do weird things as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and discovered (thanks to @datUser) that colourisation can cause lots of weird things to happen in terminals. You can remove this for execution of a single command by prefixing it with '\' so try starting mysql using `\mysql`. That worked for me.